# Is there a way to figure out how many gpu's on a node via slurm?

Tags: server, resources, slurm

I am working with a `SLURM` workload manager, and we have nodes with 4 GPUs.

The are several possible states of a node:

- allocated (all computing resources are allocated)
- mixed (part of the resources are allocated)
- idle (none of the computing resources is allocated)

Canonical way to determine the resource utilization is `sinfo` command - https://slurm.schedmd.com/sinfo.html. There are several flags and options. However, it seems, that none of them can tell how many resources on a given node are allocated ath the moment.

Say, I would like to know, for the `mixed` state, whether 1,2 or 3 GPU's are available.  Or this information is confidential and for some reason not available to users?

Comment: scontrol show nodes | grep -e CfgTRES -e  AllocTRES -e NodeName

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you run

```
scontrol show nodes
```

as a regular user, you will see a lot of information about the nodes, among which the line that look like

```
 AllocTRES=cpu=8,mem=48G,gres/gpu=2
```

tells you how many GPUs are allocated: `gres/gpu=2`. The other line

```
 CfgTRES=cpu=64,mem=257707M,billing=64,gres/gpu=2
```

tells how many GPUs are configured: `gres/gpu=2`. With these two lines, you can deduce the amount of GPUs still available on the node.